# How to check for 1000+ variables having no duplicate values?

Tags: z3

I am new to Z3 and for an open source program I want to use the z3 solver to enhance the efficiency.

I have about 1000+ values of

```
(declare-const a1 Int)
(declare-const a2 Int)
(declare-const a3 Int)
(declare-const a4 Int)
...
```

which result to

```
(declare-const x1 Int)
(declare-const x2 Int)
...
(assert (=  (+ a1 a2) x1) // in reality its not "plus" but more sophisticated
(assert (=  (+ a3 a4) x2) // however for simplicity lets keep it at that here.
...
```

Now I want to ensure that all the x1 to x500+ variables have different values and that there are no duplicates.

of course I could do

```
(assert (not (= x1 x2)))
(assert (not (= x1 x3)))
(assert (not (= x1 x4)))
...
(assert (not (= x2 x3)))
(assert (not (= x2 x4)))
...
(assert (not (= x718 719)))
```

and that would work - but is there a better solution?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Variable can be subject to array, try that

Comment: But how would that work? I don't see it, please provide a short example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `distinct` (see this [example](https://rise4fun.com/Z3/ihba)):

```
(assert (distinct x1 ... x500))
```

AFAIK, this is normally internally expanded in a sequence of inequalities, just like the one you presented in your example.

---

**Discussion:** What follows is a purely theoretical discussion about the efficiency of this encoding; `z3` is quite an efficient SMT solver, so you may not need to try anything more sophisticated than simply running the tool.

The negation of an equality (e.g. `(not (= x y))`) is generally split in a pair of inequalities:

```
x < y \/ x > y
```

Let's say `x < y` and `x > y` are renamed `B1` and `B2` respectively, the following clause is fed to the SAT engine:

```
B1 \/ B2
```

Now, given your problem, you get hundreds of these clauses. These are all related to each other at the Linear Arithmetic level, but not at the Boolean level at which the SAT engine operates. Thus, the SAT engine is likely to generate a (significant) number of inconsistent partial truth assignments, that generally violate the transitivity property of the `<` operator, e.g.

```
 x < y /\ y < z /\ z < x
```

These conflicts are going to be revealed by the Theory Solver for LRA during *early pruning* calls, and resolved at the Boolean level by learning a conflict clause blocking the invalid assignment.

What you can try:

- if your problem admits such a simplification *(if the names of `x1 ... x500` may be considered to be totally arbitrary, one could scramble them afterwards..)*, you may get better results imposing a strict total order over the variables `x1 ... x500`, e.g.

  ```
  x1 < x2 /\ x2 < x3 /\ ... /\ x499 < x500
  ```
- you can try increasing the frequency of *early pruning* calls with `z3`, if that is an available option *(note: I am not sure how often `z3` performs such calls)*
- you can try [**mcSAT**](http://csl.sri.com/users/dejan/papers/mcsat-vmcai2013.pdf) that may play nicely with this kind of constraints.

---

**EDIT:**

If the set of values that can be assigned to the variables `x_i` is finite and somewhat limited in size, you can try counting the number of variables `x_i` with a certain value using the non-standard `z3` extension for defining cardinality constraints, e.g.

```
(assert
    ((_ at-most 1)
     (= x1 0)
     (= x2 0)
     ...
     (= x500 0)
    )
)
...
% repeat for all possible values 
...
```

I am uncertain about the performance impact of this change. In normal circumstances it would positively affect the performance, because it reveals conflicting assignments earlier on (see, e.g., [[1]](http://www.patricktrentin.com/data/papers/tacas17_maxsmt.pdf)). However, you are dealing with a pretty large number of variables and a large domain of candidate values for the variables `x_i`, so flattening the search at the Boolean level may be an overkill.

Comment: the distinct keyword works nicely and results in a model with way fewer lines! :)   What it does not however is cutting down the execution time to find a solution (which is horrendous :-( ).

What I hoped would be possible is that I write every result to its array index, increasing the value there by 1 and if any array value is not 0 or 1 then there is a duplicate - which would be much faster. But I see no way How to do that in z3. I can do IFE statements, but that just allows me to return values, not e.g.

Comment: @vhthc you can count the number of variables with the same value using a pseudo-boolean constraint. I'll edit my answer later. I'm not sure whether or not it can improve the search time, because the complexity of each cardinality constraint is going to be N*LOG(N).

Comment: I implemented and tested the "distinct" solution - as you said and as I then read the documentation about it - it should be the same as my millions lines of ```(assert (not (= x2 x4)))
...
(assert (not (= x718 719)))``` however after over 8 hours it still has not completed the calculation. My million line solution however completes in 40 minutes (which is still over 10x what is acceptable). So whatever happens inside is in reality very different, making the solution unusuable :-( damn

Comment: I cannot use the cardinality constraints, as the value range is at least 0-65535 and normally greater than that. I have now inserted constraints like this: ```(assert (>= x1 0)) (assert (< x1 65536))``` and will check how it improves the speed

Comment: @vhthc Unless it takes hours to generate a million clauses internally, that's quite an interesting negative result; if no one from `z3` team is going to post here within one week I would consider trying to file a bug report in their repository and see what they reply. If you take that route, please come back here and add a link to the bug report, so others can follow the discussion!